# Contar repetidos, enumerandolos

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy intentado crear una formula que cuente los valores repetidos en una columna y que en vez de poner la cantidad de veces que se repite, que enumere esos repetidos:

He intentado con

```
=CONTAR.SI(CONCATENAR("Y1:Y",FILA(Y88)),Y88)
```

donde y88 es la fila actual y al arrastrar se genera el conjunto de formulas para cada celda, pero no sirve.

y con:

```
=CONTAR.SI({Y1:Y+FILA(Y88)},Y88)
```

Pero tampoco sirve.

Entrada

```
col1 col2
a   
b   
a   
b   
b   
a
```

Salida

```
col1 col2
a   1
b   1
a   2
b   2
b   3
a   3
```

Comment: Se pueden ordenar las filas por la columna `col1` ?

Comment: no, es una lista desordenada y no es posible ordenarla, me funciona la formula =Arrayformula(IF(A2:A="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)))) , pero me da los valores de forma desordenada.